# Modify POST String From Modal jqGrid Add/Edit Form

Tags: jquery, post, jqgrid, modal-dialog

I have a jqGrid-based application which currently retrieves data from my database and displays as intended in my grid. Inline editing is disabled; I am using modal forms for editing existing records and adding new ones. What I'm struggling with is how to access the process where data is added/edited. For example, when I edit a record and submit the form I see a POST to my api.php which contains field=value pairs. Example...

```
field1=test&field2=+2&oper=edit&id=1
```

In the above sample data, using the edit form, I changed the value in field2 - jQuery/jqGrid added the '+' in front of the value '2' as well as adding the 'oper=edit'. Ultimately I need to be append additional fields and values to the POST string but am unsure how to do so.

===Edit===
Since my original post has yielded no feedback I suppose this edit is necessary.

I have figured out where the mysterious '+' comes from in my sample data and that has been addressed.  That's not important though.

Another way to think about what I'm trying to accomplish is, one way or another, I need to add additional fields to the POST string before sending the data to the server.  For example, I might like to add a statically named field with a statically assigned value; the resulting POST string would look like:

```
field1=test&field2=2&oper=edit&id=1&widget=1
```

Notice the only difference in this sample and the previous is the addition of the 'widget' field with a value of '1'.

Comment: Trying to use the info in http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events to solve my problem but I am stuck.

Comment: Looks like the postData grid option (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) is the key... testing.

Comment: Adding postData to my grid definition did not help... seems jQuery and jqGrid are beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My source data was received via PHP as a JSON string so I:

1. PHP json_decode()
2. Looped my PHP array resulting from Step 1 to add my needed key-value pair
3. PHP json_encode()
4. set JS variable by PHP echo() the json string from Step 3

The JS variable, Step 4, was used to source my jqGrid data.

Boom!

Simple.  Solved.